# Cte within Cte in SQL

Tags: sql, db2, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have been encountered with a situation where I need to apply a where, group by condition on the result of CTE in the CTE.

Table 1 as follows

```
+---+---+---+---+
| x | y | z | w |
+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 2 |
+---+---+---+---+
```

Table 2 as follows

```
+---+---+-----+---+
| a | b |  c  | d |
+---+---+-----+---+
| 1 | m | 100 | 1 |
| 2 | n |  23 | 2 |
| 4 | o |  34 | 4 |
| 1 | m |  23 | 2 |
+---+---+-----+---+
```

Assuming I have the data of following sql query in a table called TAB

```
with cte as (
select x,y,z from table1),
cte1 as (select a,b,c from table2)
select cte.x,cte1.y,cte1.z,cte2.b,cte2.c from cte left join cte1 on cte.x=cte.a and cte1.w=cte2.d
```

Result of above CTE would be as follows

```
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
| x | y | z | w | b |  c  |
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | m | 100 |
| 2 | 3 | 4 | 2 | n |  23 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 2 | m |  23 |
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

I would like to query the following from the table TAB

```
select * from TAB where (X||b) in (select (X||b) from TAB group by (X||Y) having sum(c)=123)
```

I'm trying to formulate the SQL query as follows but it's not as i expected:

```
select * from (

with cte as (
select x,y,z from table1),
cte1 as (select a,b,c from table2)
select cte.x,cte1.y,cte1.z,cte2.b,cte2.c from cte left join cte1 on cte.x=cte.a) as TAB 

where ((X||b) in (select (X||b) from TAB group by (X||Y) having sum(c)=123))
```

The final result must be as follows

```
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
| x | y | z | w | b |  c  |
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
| 1 | 2 | 3 | 1 | m | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 6 | 2 | m |  23 |
+---+---+---+---+---+-----+
```

Comment: What is the input data, what the expected result? Often, you don't need that complexity. You can nest expressions.

Comment: What is the purpose of that CTE?

Comment: @data_henrik in reality, the table1 and table2 queries consists cross join and union all options, so needed cte to join all those results

Comment: from what I can tell, you don't need CTEs at all, you are just joining two sets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think DB2 allows CTEs in subqueries or to be nested.  Why not just write this using another CTE?

```
with cte as (
      select x,y,z from
      table1
     ),
     cte1 as (
      select a,b,c
      from table2
     ),
     tab as (
      select cte.x,cte1.y,cte1.z,cte1.w,cte2.b,cte2.c
      from cte left join
           cte1
           on cte.x=cte.a and cte1.w=cte2.d
     )
select *
from TAB
where (X||b) in (select (X||b) from TAB group by (X||Y) having sum(c)=123);
```